# Apache redirect automatically add www

Tags: apache, redirect

In apache virtualhost configuration I redirect all `http` request to `https` like this

```
<VirtualHost 10.0.0.1:80>
        ServerName example.com
        Redirect permanent / https://example.com/
</VirtualHost>
```

But after redirect it adds `www` to the url. So the url becomes `https://www.example.com/`. Unfortunately, my domain is registered without `www`. So how can I make the redirect without adding `www`?

My server ubuntu 16.04 and apache 2.4.

Answer (score 0):

You can add one more line into this setup

```
ServerAlias www.example.com
```

Also it is nice to make some redirect for the user via .htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Your first solution does not work. Also, in apache 2.4 I could not find .htaccess file

Comment: You should create that file inside Your documentRoot, but this is step2. First You have make sure that rest part of virtual hosts setup is working. Here is a very nice tutorial to follow for this probelm https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-16-04